# Drawing Image on JPanel as Background

Tags: java, background, gif

im trying to insert a gif as a background for my app. I cut all frames and renamed them f1/f2/f3/f4/f5/f6/..... I would use a timer to change the frame so it looks like an animation.

There is a total of 42 frames, so f42.png is the last frame. The code seems to be fine, but there is no result. Any help?

Global variables:

```
private String backgroundFile;
public JPanel backgroundPanel, areaImage;
private BufferedImage background;
private javax.swing.Timer timerBackground;
```

Constructor where the Timer is initialized:

```
public Game()
{
    entryWindow();

    this.setLayout(null);

    timerBackground = new javax.swing.Timer(100,this); 
    timerBackground.stop();

}
```

Animation method code:

```
private void backgroundAnimation()
{
    backgroundFile = "f"+backgroundNum+".png";
    try{
            background=ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundFile));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

        }

     backgroundPanel = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 1100,800,null);
            }
        };
    backgroundPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    backgroundPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1100, 800);
    if (backgroundNum>42)backgroundNum++; 
    else backgroundNum=1;
    add(backgroundPanel);

    backgroundPanel.setVisible(true);
}
```

Action Listener for timer:

```
if (ae.getSource() == timerBackground)
    {
        backgroundAnimation();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to show JPanel, you need to add it to something like JFrame with an BorderLayout for instance, then you need to show the JFrame. JFrame is a application window, the JPanel can be only added and drawn on Window, it can't be viewed without something on which it can draw (like app Window). Beside that you don't need to create new JPanel each time the animation changes, just make a setter for the current image to show, and after assigning the image call repaint(), the `ImagePanel` could be like this:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

 private volatile BufferedImage image;

 public void showImage(BufferedImage image) {
  this.image=image;
  repaint();
 }
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.drawImage(image, 0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
 }
}
```

add it to your JFrame at application start, also set the LayoutManager of JFrame to BorderLayout preferably, because without that your panel will have size(0,0) since you didn't set it, and it could be one of reasons why you don't see it (you can't see something which is 0 pixel in size, can you?).

Then in your timer just call the `ImagePanel` method `public void showImage(BufferedImage image)` with the image to show. If that's don't solve your problem, then post your entire code. As without that i'm just guessing, but those are common problems, so there's big chance you hit something from this.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few issues here 
1. Assuming your `Game` class is extending `JFrame`, You need to add the JPanel to the `ContentPane` of the `JFrame`. Use one of the approaches `setContentPane(backgroundPanel);` or `getContentPane().add(backgroundPanel)`

2. You are not using a `LayoutManager`. So either use a `LayoutManager` or set the Size of the 'JFrame' and 'JPanel' explicitly using `setBounds()` method. I would recommend using a `LayoutManager`.
3. The `JPanel` or any `Component` for that matter does not automatically refresh itself. Once you change the image, you need to call `repaint()` on your JPanel.
4. You dont need to create a new `JPanel` every time you change the image. Just extend the `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent()`like you have done. Use the `Timer` to change the image of that single instance and call `repaint()` with every change.

The complete example, with hat output you are seeing will help understand the problem better and give you a solution. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here, but first let me answer your question:

You are creating a new `JPanel` and add it to the `Game` on every run through. That is wrong, since you add infinite panels to your `Game`
Also in your if/else you have a wrong condition. You increase the iterator when it is greater 42. You probably mean lesser than 42.

Here is how I would do it:

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    private int currImage = 0;
    private BufferedImage[] backgroundImages;

    public BackgroundPanel() {
        int numberOfImages = 42;
        backgroundImages = new BufferedImage[42];
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfImages; i++) {
            String backgroundFile = "f" + i + ".png";
            backgroundImages[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(backgroundFile));
        }
    }

    public void nextImage() {
        /*if(currImage <= 42) currImage++;
        else currImage = 1;*/
        if(currImage++ > 42) currImage = 1;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImages[currImage], 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

You need to add this panel ONCE to your "Game":

```
//Somewhere in your Game
private BackgroundPanel backgroundPanel;

...
...

public Game() {
    entryWindow();

    this.setLayout(null);
    backgroundPanel = new backgroundPanel();
    backgroundPanel.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    add(backgroundPanel);

    timerBackground = new javax.swing.Timer(100,this); 
    timerBackground.stop();
}
```

Your timer:

```
if (ae.getSource() == timerBackground) {
    backgroundPanel.nextImage();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's easier to put the background on JLabel. It requires only 3 lines of code and works fine! :) Hope it helps for anyone that will have the same problem :)

All you have to do is copy this code, change the name (i have all pictures in a folder called "Images") with any kind of Java supported picture/video/.... (just change the suffix .gif to your file format) and at last the size. Good luck! :)

```
public JLabel backgroundGIF;     

backgroundGIF = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/background.gif")));
backgroundGIF.setBounds(0,0,1100,800);
add(backgroundGIF);
```

Comment: your question is "Drawing Image on JPanel as Background" this does not answer the original question - it answers the question you have in your head